# Exclude from result if its column contains any value in list

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have a SQL table that has the id's `1` through `30` but I want to exclude the numbers 7,10,21 from the sql.

How would I do this without writing something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBL 
WHERE COL <> '7' AND COL <> '10' AND COL <> '21'
```

But instead, write something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBL 
WHERE COL NOT IN (@IDS)
```

When trying the example, it works if `@IDS` is equal to one number, but if it is equal to multiple numbers all records show.

To clarify the reason it has to be a list of numbers is that is how it is passed to the SQL. I am unable to change how the data is passed.

To clarify more because I should have stated it in the original question. I do not know the exact numbers being passed into the SQL Statement, the ones I provided were for the example, but it could be any number.

Comment: You would have to write `NOT IN ('7', '10', '21')`

Comment: Seems like a duplicate [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause/)

Comment: I don't know the numbers coming in. That is the problem.

Comment: I would assume that `Col` is an `int`, so is `@IDS` a table variable?

Comment: `@IDS` is a string value, so is `Col` Sorry for not clarifying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write this as:

```
WHERE COL NOT IN (7, 10, 21)
```

If you want to pass in a string, then you can split it.  In SQL Server 2016+, you an use `string_split()` (and you can get `SPLIT()` functions for earlier versions on the web).

```
WHERE COL NOT IN (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT('7,10,21'))
```

Do note that this does conversion from string to integers, which might prevent the use of indexes.  So:

```
WHERE COL NOT IN (SELECT CONVERT(INT, value) FROM STRING_SPLIT('7,10,21'))
```

Or `NOT EXISTS`:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 
              FROM STRING_SPLIT('7,10,21')
              WHERE ?.COL = TRY_CONVERT(INT, value) 
             )
```

Comment: I would not use `TRY_CONVERT`, when some value will be converted to `NULL` then entire query will return 0 rows.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda has a point there. If you change the `IN` to an `EXISTS` you could continue to use `TRY_CONVERT` and not have the behaviour though. That would then avoid an error if you can't convert to an `int` too.

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent two days trying to do this and you solved it in seconds... I didn't even know `SPLIT_STRING` was a thing.